# Replacing with Dynamic variable in preg_replace

Tags: variables, dynamic, preg-replace

I'm trying the following code:

```
$t = '12<-- AB_C -->';
$AB_C = 'abc';
echo preg_replace('/\<-- ([A-Z_]+) --\>/', "$$1", $t);
```

I want to get "12abc" , but it outputs: 12$AB_C , so, it not recognize the replacement as dynamic variable.
Is it any way to use the matched word in preg_replace() as a variable, or dynamic variable?

Edit:

For those who look for a solution to this problem, the '/e' flag, which evalates the replacement, solved the problem, and returns the results i want, using:

```
preg_replace('/\<-- ([A-Z_]+) --\>/e', "$$1", $t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)?

It's like `preg_replace`, but with a callback function that takes an array `$matches` where `$matches[0]` is the entire match, `$matches[1]` is the first capturing group, etc.

Perhaps something like (sorry, not tested):

```
 preg_replace_callback(
        '/\<-- ([A-Z_]+) --\>/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return $$matches[1];' // attempt to retrieve value of $AB_C
        ),
        $t
    );
```